# How do I Print something from a file that serialized, in a particular order?

Tags: java

So I am just working on this little game, everything works it's just my scoring class that is giving me trouble. So I want to print out a list like this
ex... (I have it to where I sort by wins.)

1:John Wins: 2 Draws: 1 Loses: 2

2:Joe Wins: 1 Draws: 2 Loses: 1

3:Guest Wins: 0 Draws: 0 Loses: 0

4:Guest Wins: 0 Draws: 0 Loses: 0

The problem is that when I re-read the file it only prints out the new name like this:

1:Adam Wins: 2 Draws: 1 Loses: 2

2:Guest Wins: 0 Draws: 0 Loses: 0

3:Guest Wins: 0 Draws: 0 Loses: 0

4:Guest Wins: 0 Draws: 0 Loses: 0

As you can se it doesn't print out the other names that are in the file like John and Joe. I print Guest when the user doesn't enter a name so it's the default name.

How can I make it save the previous names and add in the new names and compare and sort them than print them.

Also the reason why I have score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0)); in my constructor is because I want to add the default scores but I think I am doing it wrong so feel free to suggest any changes. I was trying to have it when the file is empty to initialize the array with the default values.

Another thing how can I print out the elements in the arraylist on a JtextArea so that they are printed like lists?

```
    public class Score1Frame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ImageIcon pressPlayAgain = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/PlayAgainScorePressed.png"));
    ImageIcon unpressPlayAgain = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/PlayAgainScoreUnPressed.png"));
    ImageIcon pressQuit = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/QuitScorePressed.png"));
    ImageIcon unpressQuit = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/QuitScoreUnpressed.png"));
    GameFrame scores;
    public ArrayList<Score1> score = new ArrayList<Score1>();

    Score1SubmitFrame add;
    // The file 
    private String scoreFile = "score";

    File file = new File(scoreFile);

    /**
     * Creates new form Score1Frame
     */
    public Score1Frame() {
        initComponents();
        //Score1SubmitFrame adds = Score1SubmitFrame();
        setSize(640, 515);
        // Don't allow resizeable
        setResizable(false);
        // Set the title
        setTitle("Rock Paper Scissors
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
        fileEmpty();
        addScore();
        addScoresToFile();
        sortScore();

        displayScore();


    }

    public void fileEmpty() {

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            if (br.readLine() == null) {
                // If the file is empty call the default scores method
//                for (int i = 0; i >= 5; i++) {
//                    defaultScore();
//                }

                score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
                score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
                score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
                score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
                score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
                System.out.println("File has default values since it was empty");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please close the program, as we will try to resolve the issue.", "File Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //createFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It seems as there was an issue displaying the leaderboards. Please close the game and reopen the game. Thank You", "Can't Open Leaderboards", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }

    }

//    public void createFile() {
//
//        try {
//            // Create the file
//            FileOutputStream fileScore = new FileOutputStream(file);
//            // Close the file
//            fileScore.close();
//        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
//
//        } catch (IOException ex) {
//
//        }
//
//    }
    // The method that adds the score to the arraylist
    public void addScore() {
        // Score1SubmitFrame object to allow me acess to the class
        add = new Score1SubmitFrame();
        // GameFrame object to allow me access to the class
        scores = new GameFrame();
        // Add the score to the arraylist
        score.add(new Score1(add.userName(), scores.getFinalWin(), scores.getFinalDraw(), scores.getFinalLose()));
        // Declare an iterator
        Iterator<Score1> list = score.iterator();
        // Go through the arraylist
        while (list.hasNext()) {
            Score1 scoreAdd = list.next();
            System.out.println("Score was added");
        }
    }
    // The method that adds the score to the file
    public void addScoresToFile() {

        try {
            // Create the file
            FileOutputStream myFile = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // Create the object that will write to the file
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(myFile);
            // Iterate through the array
            for (Score1 h : score) {
                // Write the scores to the file
                os.writeObject(h);
            }
            myFile.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Score1Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Score1Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void displayScore() {
        int id = 1;

        try {

            FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(file);
            ObjectInputStream openFile = new ObjectInputStream(inFile);

            //score = (ArrayList<Score1>) openFile.readObject();
            //Score1 b = (Score1) openFile.readObject();
//            for (Score1 add : score) {
//                  //highScore.setText(id + ": " + add.name + " Wins: " + add.wins + ", Draws: " + add.draws + ", Loses: " + add.loses);
//                //highScore.setText(score);
//                System.out.println(score);
//                id++;
//            }
            try {
                while (true) {
                    Score1 bc = (Score1) openFile.readObject();
                    score.add(bc);
                    System.out.println(bc.name + " Wins : " + bc.wins);
                }
            } catch (EOFException e) {

            }
            System.out.println("---- Display ----");
//            for (Score1 s : score) {
//                System.out.println(id + ": " + s.name + " Wins: " + s.wins + " Draws: " + s.draws + " Loses: " + s.loses);
//                highScore.setText(id + ":" + s.name + " Wins: " + s.wins + " Draws: " + s.draws + " Loses: " + s.loses);
//                id++;
//                if (id >= 5) {
//                    break;
//                }
//            }
            // Test here
            System.out.println("---------------------- Other -------------------");
            Iterator<Score1> list;

            for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
                list = score.iterator();

                while(list.hasNext()){
                    Score1 s = list.next();
                    highScore.setText(id + ":" + s.name + " Wins: " + s.wins + " Draws: " + s.draws + " Loses: " + s.loses);
                    System.out.println(id + ":" + s.name + " Wins: " + s.wins + " Draws: " + s.draws + " Loses: " + s.loses);
                    id++;
                    if (id == 5){
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
            openFile.close();
            inFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(scoreFile, scoreFile);
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Score1Frame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {

        }

        addScoresToFile();
//        for (Score1 d : score) {
//            //System.out.println(d.name +"Wins: "+ d.wins);
//            highScore.setText(id + ": " + d.name + " Wins: " + d.wins + ", Draws: " + d.draws + ", Loses: " + d.loses);
//            id++;
//        }

    }


    public void writeScores() {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fs;
            fs = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(score);
            os.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            //createFile();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please close the program and try again as we try to resolve the issue ", "File Not Found", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "It seems as there was an issue displaying the leaderboards. Please close the game and reopen. Thank You", "Can't Open Leaderboards", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        } finally {

        }
    }

    public void defaultScore() {
        score.add(new Score1(null, 0, 0, 0));
    }

    public void sortScore() {
        Iterator<Score1> list = score.iterator();
        int rank = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            Collections.sort(score, new ScoreComparator());
            list = score.iterator();
            while (list.hasNext()) {
                Score1 b = list.next();
                //System.out.println(rank +": "+ b.name + "Wins: "+ b.wins + ", Draws: "+ b.draws + ", Loses: "+b.loses);
                //highScore.setText(rank + ": " + b.name + " Wins: " + b.wins + ", Draws: " + b.draws + ", Loses: " + b.loses + "\n");
                //rank++;
            }
        }
    }

    private class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Score1> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Score1 s1, Score1 s2) {
            //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            if (s1.wins == s2.wins) {
                return 0;
            } else if (s1.wins > s2.wins) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> save the previous names and add the new names

You have to open the file in append mode.

You can use another implementation of [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-) constructor i.e.

```
public FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-)

> compare and sort them then print them.

I suggest you to look at `SortedSet` and [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). Use it with Score Comparator to automatically sort the element whenever you add an item to the `Set`.

Comment: Okay that worked, so 1 of my problems is solved thank you. But why doesn't my class save the score. Like in the example I posted up at the top

Comment: You have not closed your `FileStream` in `writeScores()` method.

Comment: I know how to sort it is just I don't know how to save the info into the file and get it back when my game resets. Also sorry for the late reply

Comment: Please revert back if you are still facing issues while saving into the file.